# macOS 11.2.3 bashrc not reconizing common flags

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to configure my terminal, but my .bashrc file is not recognizing the common flags.

Here is what my .bash_profile looks like:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This is what my .bashrc file looks like:

```
export PS1="\u@\h\w $ "
```

And this is what my command prompt looks at the end:

```
$ source .bashrc
\u@\h\w $
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS 11.2.3 defaults to the zsh shell so bash dotfiles and prompt formatting will not apply. Type ‘ps’ to verify which shell you are running.

Comment: In zsh, you would use: export PROMPT=“%n@%m %~ $” to achieve the prompt you are after